# How to take input both positive & negative as an integer ? Help me to solve this problem

Tags: python

> Using the method of looping, write a program to print the table of 9
>   till N in the format as follows: (N is input by the user)
>
> 9 18 27...
>
> Print NULL if 0 is input
>
> Input Description: A positive integer is provided as an input.
>
> Output Description: Print the table of nine with single space between
>   the elements till the number that is input.
>
> Sample Input:
>
> ```
> 3
> ```
>
> Sample Output:
>
> ```
> 9 18 27
> ```

My solution is:

```
x = int(input(" "))
if x > 0:
    count = 1
    while count<=x:
        z = 9*count
        print(z, end=" ")
        count += 1
else:
    print("NULL")
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Just curious. Why do you worry about negative inputs when it is clearly given that the input will be a positive integer ? `int()` is capable of handling both positive and negative values.

Comment: just wanted to know is their is another way to solve the question because my program is not getting passed of even 1 case of this question i dont understand where i am going to wrong.

Comment: Hi and welcome! You should edit your post and ask for an actual question.

Answer (score -1):

Use `abs` function. So you get only positive values. If you want both positive and negative, you can use normal `input` function.